# How can I say something like "It has been saved successfully" using a short sentence?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, traduction, questions

How can I say something like "It has been saved successfully" in French using a short sentence?
I thought about "Votre note a été sauvegardé avec succès", but it's too long I think :/ 
The sentence will be displayed quickly

Ps: "It has been saved successfully", is it too long? I'm thinking about something like "Saved", but I don't know if it's grammatically correct or polite :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sauvegardé* (Saved), *Note sauvegardée* (Note saved) or *Sauvegarde effectuée* (Save completed) would all be fine.

I wouldn't add *avec succès* because telling it was saved already implies the operation was successful.